# NAD conversion in Mexixo

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, datum, mexico

I am looking for the file "Mexico.gsb" which used with ArcGIS when datum shifting from NAD27 to NAD83 in Mexico.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS doesn't have a mexico.gsb file that converts NAD27/NAD83 in Mexico. Mexico never converted officially to NAD83 that I know of, although data was used in the calculation of NAD83.

Existing transformations were built by the US, either the military for onshore or by oil & gas companies or contractors for offshore areas.